# RaspiMJPEG could not creat camera

Tags: raspbian, streaming-video, raspicam

I recently tried out the rpi cam web interface (v6.0.2) on the raspberry pi 2, running rasbian.

Although the camera (rpi stock camera, connected by csi)  works fine and the webpage it produces is normal, it keeps showing up a popup saying that there is an error.
Raspistill works perfectly, too.

The log (in the rpi cam web interface webpage) shows this over and over again (at least once every second):

```
{2015/07/30 01:26:51} RaspiMJPEG Version 5.2.4
{2015/07/30 01:26:51} Error: Could not create camera
```

Is there some thing wrong with the camera or it is bug with the software?

Comment: Does `raspivid` work?  If so the camera is presumably fine.